# How to display JSON entries in textboxes and move through the string when clicking on a button?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I am building a windows form application in VS 2017 C#, where I ask the user to enter their host IP address, username, password etc. This information is then saved to a JSON file to separate string [Click here to see the application interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD6gM.png). The user can then add as many as they want information and press **ADD** to add a new JSON string with the number of records. The JSON string looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Record": 1,
    "IPaddress": "192.168.6.***",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "nautitech",
    "password": "nautitech",
    "sourcefolder": "...../..../..../.....",
    "destfolder": "...../..../..../.....",
    "filextension": "txt",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  },
  {
    "Record": 2,
    "IPaddress": "192.168.255.***",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": "...../..../..../.....",
    "destfolder": "...../..../..../.....",
    "filextension": "json",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  },
  {
    "Record": 3,
    "IPaddress": "192.168.10.***",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": "...../..../..../.....",
    "destfolder": "...../..../..../.....",
    "filextension": "db",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  }
]
```

The code to write these JSON string is below:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Add", "ADD", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                filePath = @"C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\Companies\Nautitech Mining Systems Pty Ltd\Code\JSON\app-db.json";
                // Update json data string
                //jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataloggerList);
                //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData);
                string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

                var currentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Datalogger>>(text);

                //Create new Datalogger

                Datalogger myself = new Datalogger

                {

                    Record = ++count,
                    IPaddress = textBox2.Text,
                    Machinename = textBox8.Text,
                    username = textBox4.Text,
                    password = textBox3.Text,
                    sourcefolder = textBox7.Text,
                    destfolder = textBox6.Text,
                    filextension = textBox5.Text,

                };

                if (currentList != null && currentList.Any())
                {
                    var lastRecordNumner = currentList.OrderBy(q => q.Record).Last().Record;
                    myself.Record = lastRecordNumner + 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    currentList = new List<Datalogger>();
                }

                currentList.Add(myself);

                string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Activate();
            }
```

**Requirement:**
When the user enters the information and adds multiple JSON strings, I want to give the user the ability to click on **Forward**, **Backward**, **Last** and **First** to move through the JSON file and display the information on the textboxes, so they can see the information without opening the JSON, [Someting like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXl42.png) (This is created manually) Ultimately the user can move through the JSON file and update the information using the **Save** button.

Comment: Just deserialize json to array of objects (write dto class for that) and work with the array

Comment: When I deserialize JSON to an array, how to track the JSON string position by clicking on forward and backward button?

Comment: forget about json after deserializing, use the array (forward - next element of the array, backward - previous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read your json again and deserialize it and enter a background counter like i at cycles. In according with this counter you need to get your information from deserialized list. For example like this.

```
#region Global Scope
public int counter;
#endregion
....
var map = JObject.Parse(jsonTextFromFile);
var serversList = (List) map;
var server;
int i = 0;
foreach (var elem in serverList)
{
   if (i == counter)
      server = elem;
   i++;
}
...
```

Comment: Is this code tested on your debugger, It doesn't seem to work, Can you please also provide more background

Comment: its just a logic example